# Maven error when importing jpetstore of Spring3.0 to Springsource Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, maven

I downloaded the JPetstore from SVN and there are maven errors that I can't solve

I have tried running maven-update dependency and maven-update project configuration and it doesn't help.

The errors are below:

```
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 
'C:\Users\YYC\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jstl\1.2\jstl-1.2.jar

ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:
```

Maven:2.2.1

Spring JPetstore https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/jpetstore/trunk/org.springframework.samples.jpetstore/

I want to understand the errors and resolve them so that I can build and run the JPetStore code.

Comment: Is jstl library there, in the repository?

Comment: Updating the Spring artefact to 3.0.5.RELEASE fixes this error, but causes others

Comment: I see no jstl library in my repository. But my question is why maven can not download jstl to the repository for me? Cause I see the dependency description in the pom.xml file

Comment: To Rob, it works by changing to <spring.version>3.0.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.version>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the answer is to edit [pom.xml](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/jpetstore/trunk/org.springframework.samples.jpetstore/pom.xml) to reference **Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE** replacing the 3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in the file.

Comment: It's not clear to me that the jPetStore app is actively maintained by SpringSource as I could not find it on GitHub where they have moved their main projects. Would be great if we could contribute to the maintenance of this app.

Comment: plz find the project in https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/jpetstore/trunk/org.springframework.samples.jpetstore/